# minimum height with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I'm using the following function to give a height value to a div based on the window height. But for very small screens I'd like to add a 400px minimum height.

```
  $('.info').height(function(){
       return $(window).height() * 0.7;
    });
```

So for window's heights less than 630px give the `.info` class a height value of 400px.

Any help would be great.

*edit:*

If the window is less than 630px add this height to its css:

```
.info {height:400px;}
```

Otherwise find * 0.7 of the window height and use that.

Comment: actually what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.info').css('min-height', function(){ $(window).height() * 0.7 });
```

Try this it will work.....

Answer (score 0):

try this but you should check the height of window first to make sure it worth increasing

```
var windowh=$(window).height()* 0.7;
$('.info').height(windowh);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.info').height(function(){
       if($(window).height() <= 630)
       {
           return ($(window).height() * 0.7) + 400;
       }

       return ($(window).height() * 0.7)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Math.max function.

```
$('.info').height(function(){
  return Math.max($(window).height() * 0.7, 400)+'px';
});
```